# Is there a way to change background color for a table in onenote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

In word or excel or power point you can change the background color of a table or selected rows or columns of a table, but I can't find a way to do this is onenote.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to change the background color of cells in a table in OneNote http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/in-onenote-tables-how-can-i-change-the-background/5fe682ea-5a07-43dd-815a-2b4d8af646d5.

Comment: OneNote 2013 now has RMB >> Table >> Shading.

Answer (score 23):

## In Microsoft OneNote 2013+:

In a table:

- highlight the row, cell or column you want to shade
- right click and select table
- shade
- select your color and voila! Your column is shaded.

Comment: Are you sure using OneNote to do this and note Word? I don't have a shade option.

Comment: The menu option exists in 2013, but not in 2010.  If you apply color in 2013 it does not show up in 2010 (I have a table shared between both versions right now).

Comment: Does this only apply since onenote 2013?

Comment: This also works in OneNote 2016 (Plus)

Answer (score 4):

Create a shape in Word and fill with desired colour.
Copy into OneNote and 'send to back' behind table.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this should work but it is less than ideal, I wish microsoft added this feature to the next version.

Comment: Nice workaround, won't try it though :) Wondering why Microsoft left out such a basic feature...

Answer (score 2):

I'm on One Note for Mac so not sure if this is the same on Windows.

1. Highlight the row/cells to be shaded
2. In the toolbar, click on "Table" tab which appears.
3. Locate "Shading" at the right-end of that tab.

It is odd this does not appear from the context (right-click) menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is with "OneNote for Windows 10" - which is the half-baked, crippled "successor" to OneNote 2016, but it seems to be what we all end up using.

Just highlight/select the desired cells with the mouse, then when you let go of the mouse button to complete the selection, a context/format menu appears.  The paint can is "Shading".

Here's how it looks in a screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot of Shading OneNote Cells in OneNote for Windows 10]

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure on previous versions: I'm using 2016).

If it helps, One Note auto creates what looks like a table if you tab between data columns. N.B. This is not a 'proper' table and you can't format to shade a row etc

If you go to the **Insert** tab and create a table from there, you can then change the formatting by right clicking, choosing table, and then a list of options will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the table cells.
Click on the "Layout" tab in OneNote.
Select Shading and choose the color.
This link should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_CBXFLqM4A